# Assigning multiple data to var inside loop and trying to use var outside the loop

Tags: php, loops, variables, while-loop, scope

I have 5 pieces of data.

I put all 5 pieces of data into a variable inside a while loop. Then, I am trying to that use variable outside of the while loop - but have all of the data that was put in, still echo.

Currently, I am able to put the data in, and successfully get 1 piece of data out. I would like to echo all 5 pieces of data.

Code:

```
        $s = <a search query that gets data from external db>
        while($data = $r->FetchRow($s)) { 
        $addr = 'test address';
        if($data['image'] == '') { $data['image'] = 'nophoto.jpg';}
            $a = '<div style="height: 85px; width: 100%;"><img src="http://website.com/'.$data['image'].'" align="left" border="0" hspace="15" alt="Click for details" height="85px" width="120px" />'.$addr.'';
                                    }
        $m = "This is a test message <br />" .
        $m = "".$a."" . 
        $m = "This is the end of a test message";
        echo $m;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your loop, you are assigning value to `$a`.

So, the latest value is overwriting the old value and hence you are getting the last value.

If you want to get all the data, you need to append `$a` in loop.

**Corrected code:**

```
$a = '';
$s = <a search query that gets data from external db>
while($data = $r->FetchRow($s)) {
 $addr = 'test address';
 if($data['image'] == '') {
  $data['image'] = 'nophoto.jpg';
 }
 $a .= '<div style="height: 85px; width: 100%;"><img src="http://website.com/'.$data['image'].'" align="left" border="0" hspace="15" alt="Click for details" height="85px" width="120px" />'.$addr.'';
}
$m = "This is a test message <br />" .
$m = "".$a."" . 
$m = "This is the end of a test message";
echo $m;
```

Comment: Perfect answer! Thank you for explaining that.